# 2D array to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've got array: int `i[20][30]`. What is the fastest way to make `int**` pointer to use on it?

My friend just wrote function which uses same size arrays and my function is on pointers and I need to pass his data.

Comment: The fastest way is don't. Anyway why not just use `std::array`?

Comment: Add the function prototypes

Comment: A 2d array simply doesn't have the same memory layout as a pointer to pointer would expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[20][30];       // data as 2D array
int *ap[20];         // array of pointers
for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    ap[j] = a[j];    // convert array to pointers
// can now pass `ap` to function expecting `int **`...
```

Comment: @Daniel: thanks - the use of `i` for an array name muddled my brain - now fixed.

Comment: Why would one downvote this answer? Has anybody a better idea to make a function expecting an `int**` with an `int[20][30]`?

Comment: Ain't there a faster way?

Comment: @oneat: "faster" ? what do you mean by "faster" ?

Comment: I believe that `ip` should be `int *ip[30];`, no?

Comment: @sftrabbit No, `int i[20][30]` is an array of 20 `int[30]`, so 20 is correct.

Comment: @oneat You're asking to convert between two incompatible things. That kind of conversion takes some effort.

Comment: @sftrabbit: no, it's 20 rows of 30 columns (or 20 strings of 30 characters if you prefer).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, of course, I'm also getting mixed up with these variable names.

Comment: I've changed the array/pointer names above now as it was somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `int **` pointer to that array directly, it wouldn't make any sense. If you want to access the array as a block of memory you can just use:

```
int *p = (int *)i; // you can go to up (p + 20*30)
```

Otherwise you need a pointer to an array of `int[30]`, i.e.

```
int (*p)[30] = &i[0]; // points to first row
```

With the first one, because of the cast, you can then define:

```
int **p2 = &p;
```

And you can access the array with `*(*p2 + n)`. You've cast away the array dimensions, but as long as you use them in the pointer calculations, it's all valid, i.e. `*(*p2 + 35)` refers to row 2, column 6 (one row of 30, plus element 5 of the next). This is very quick, but if the function needs to operate on the array using the original dimensions, this wouldn't work (since it isn't an array of pointers).

Answer (score 0):

you cant change `int i[20][30]` to `int **` except of manually go over the data and build it.
but, something that may help you, every xD array in c++ is just a 1D array with a somehow complexed way to access a member.

Example:

```
#define MaxX 20
#define MaxY 30
int i[MaxX][MaxY];
...
//When you write:
i[x][y] = something;
//It's actually been translate to:
i[x * MaxY + y] = something;
```